# How to animate a button with Timeline?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to animate a button. I want to make it change its position after clicking on it. I wrote such code, but it does not work. In this case, no errors appear in the console. The button simply does not respond to pressing.

```
double stopPosition = 100;
KeyValue kk2 = new KeyValue(btn.layoutXProperty(), stopPosition, Interpolator.LINEAR);
KeyFrame kk = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000),kk2);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kk);
timeline.setCycleCount(1);

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
                timeline.play();
            }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you placed the button in some layout that takes care of positioning. If you modify `layoutX` this means during the next layout pass the `Button` is simply put back "where it belongs" by the parent layout.

If you want to move the `Button`, you should choose a different layout as parent or use the `translateX` property instead. `translateX` moves the `Button` relative to the position where the parent layout places it (`layoutX`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I think now I will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You should animate translation coordinates, not layout coordinates.

```
double deltaPosition = 100; //translation gets added to your current layoutX
KeyValue kk2 = new KeyValue(btn.translateXProperty(), deltaPosition, Interpolator.LINEAR);
KeyFrame kk = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000),kk2);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kk);
timeline.setCycleCount(1);

btn.setOnAction(ae -> {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        timeline.play();
    }
);
```

Layout values are overwritten by layout panes like `HBox`, `AnchorPane`, but not by `Group` or `Pane`. Alternatively, set `setManaged(false)` on the button so the parent container won't interfere with its layout but, you'll have to do all layout by yourself.